# PHP Array element to string

Tags: php, arrays

I use PHPExcel to put elements of my Excel file into an array. I then do

```
print_r($worksheets);
```

Where $worksheets is the array created through PHPExcel.  The output is

```
Array ( 
    [enquiry] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => 86.141.247.93 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 188.141.76.143 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2.29.20.161 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

What I need to do is pass each of these IPs as a String to a function.  So what I am trying is this

```
foreach($worksheets as $ip) {
    $count = 0;
    if ($SpamProtecter->CheckIP($ip[$count][0])) {
        print_r("SPAM");
    } else {
        print_r("GOOD");
    }
    $count++;
}
```

The problem I have is that it only prints out one result.  How can I pass each array element as a String to CheckIP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have an intermediate level in your array. Remember, `foreach` iterates over the top level of elements. You have 3 tiers here

```
foreach($worksheets['enquiry'] as $ip) { //iterate tier 1
    if ($SpamProtecter->CheckIP($ip[0])) { //grab tier 3
        print_r("SPAM");
    } else {
       print_r("GOOD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$worksheets` array only has a single key: `enquiry`, which is why you're only getting a single result output.  Try this:

```
foreach($worksheets['enquiry']) as $ip) {
    if($SpamProtector->CheckIP($ip[0]) {
    // ...
```

I think you can also get rid of that inner `$count` variable since it is not used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This could work

```
foreach($worksheets['enquiry'] as $ip) {

    if ($SpamProtecter->CheckIP($ip[0])) {
        print_r("SPAM");
    } else {
        print_r("GOOD");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) works well in situtations where you want to perform an action on each element in an array.

```
array_walk($worksheets["enquiry"], 
           function ($a) use ($SpamProtecter) { 
                echo $SpamProtecter->CheckIP($a[0])?"GOOD":"BAD";
           });
```